# How can I show the elapsed time instead of remaining in Rhythmbox?

Tags: rhythmbox

Can I configure Rhythmbox to show the elapsed time instead of remaining time?

[image]

**Figure 1: Current configuration showing remaining time**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply you can click on that. After clicking you can see elapsed time.

[image]